# Copy file from web to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

There is a document on the web that I want to store in my Google Drive. The only way I know to do this is saving the document on my computer and then upload it again to my Google Drive.

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this IFTTT receipt](https://ifttt.com/channels/google_drive/actions/78-upload-file-from-url).

> #### Upload file from URL
>
> This Action will download a file at a given URL and add it to Google Drive at the path you specify.